# Can't let a script built upon requests produce all the image links from a webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to grab all the images from this [webpage](https://www.pexels.com/sv-se/sok/office/) using requests. When I run the script that I've created so far is not getting anything at all. Although the images are available within page source, I can't get this script to work. I wish to scrape all the images which show up while scrolling to the bottom. I also noticed that some link `https://www.pexels.com/sv-se/sok/office/?format=js&seed=&page=4&type=` found in the dev tools generating all the content incrementing the page number attached to it. But I failed to produce images making use of that link as well.

I've written so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.pexels.com/sv-se/sok/office/'

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.83 Safari/537.36'    
    s.headers['referer'] = 'https://www.pexels.com/sv-se/'
    r = s.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    for item in soup.select("a.photo-item__link > img.photo-item__img"):
        print(item['data-large-src'])
```

***How can I grab all the image links from that webpage using requests?***

Comment: To get all image, I think this should work: `soup.find_all("img", {"class": "photo-item__img"})`, now in scroll, you are correct that there one API endpoint which is requested and getting other images as well. In that case, you can try Selenium for this or see if you can do something with endpoint

Comment: That what you have suggested I'm already doing @Shashank. The only difference is that I'm using `.select()` instead of `.find_all()`.

Comment: When I look at the actual text returned, it is not the expected page contents but rather it seems to contain a captcha challenge.

Comment: I tried to open an image and read the headers for the request. It requires cookies and also a path. Try to get the cookie and then understand how the path is generated. That will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this script to get all image links from the URL:

```
import re
import requests

url = 'https://www.pexels.com/sv-se/sok/office/?format=js&seed=&page={page}&type='

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0',
           'Referer': 'https://www.pexels.com/sv-se/sok/office/',
           'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
           'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5'}
cookies = {'locale': 'sv-SE'}

page = 1
picture_num = 1
while True:
    data = requests.get(url.format(page=page), headers=headers, cookies=cookies).text
    total_pages = int(re.search(r'"totalPages"\s*:\s*(\d+)', data).group(1))
    imgs = re.findall(r"infiniteScrollingAppender\.append\('(.*?)',\s*'", data)

    if page > total_pages:
        break

    for d in imgs:
        d = d.replace(r'\'', "'").replace(r'\"', '"').replace(r'\/', "/").replace(r'\n', '\n')
        print('{}/{} picture_num={}'.format(page, total_pages, picture_num), BeautifulSoup(d, 'html.parser').select_one('[data-large-src]')['data-large-src'])
        picture_num += 1

    page += 1
```

Prints:

```
1/204 picture_num=1 https://images.pexels.com/photos/2041627/pexels-photo-2041627.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=650&w=940
1/204 picture_num=2 https://images.pexels.com/photos/3987020/pexels-photo-3987020.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=650&w=940
1/204 picture_num=3 https://images.pexels.com/photos/3810754/pexels-photo-3810754.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=650&w=940
1/204 picture_num=4 https://images.pexels.com/photos/3178818/pexels-photo-3178818.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=650&w=940
1/204 picture_num=5 https://images.pexels.com/photos/3861958/pexels-photo-3861958.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=650&w=940
1/204 picture_num=6 https://images.pexels.com/photos/3862365/pexels-photo-3862365.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=650&w=940
1/204 picture_num=7 https://images.pexels.com/photos/3746932/pexels-photo-3746932.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=650&w=940
1/204 picture_num=8 https://images.pexels.com/photos/3277806/pexels-photo-3277806.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=650&w=940
1/204 picture_num=9 https://images.pexels.com/photos/1957477/pexels-photo-1957477.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=650&w=940
1/204 picture_num=10 https://images.pexels.com/photos/3184296/pexels-photo-3184296.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=650&w=940
1/204 picture_num=11 https://images.pexels.com/photos/3184357/pexels-photo-3184357.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=650&w=940
1/204 picture_num=12 https://images.pexels.com/photos/4064641/pexels-photo-4064641.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=650&w=940
1/204 picture_num=13 https://images.pexels.com/photos/2041629/pexels-photo-2041629.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=650&w=940
1/204 picture_num=14 https://images.pexels.com/photos/3184359/pexels-photo-3184359.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=650&w=940


...and so on.
```

---

[image]

Comment: I'm sure when you provided this solution, it worked for you @Andrej Kesely as I've always found your solution very useful. However, in this very case the script is throwing error at this line `total_pages`, so I printed the text and found this line `Attention Required! | Cloudflare` within. Thanks.

Comment: @MITHU You've got Captcha page from Cloudflare - try to add/remove HTTP headers and/or cookies. Do you run your code from some VPS (Cloudflare might block their IP addresses)? For my case, I had to add `locale` Cookie and `'Accept-Language'` HTTP header.

Comment: Are you still getting it to work in your side? If it is, I'll accept this answer and try later bringing about few changes myself. Thanks.

Comment: @MITHU Yes, now running it at home and it works (previously I ran it from my workplace). Added screenshot from the output.